# Check images on server folder against images on database

Tags: php, mysql, image, file, comparison

I was wondering if is there anything pre-made to compare a single image folder on the server against a field on a mysql database to unlink/remove files not needed from the server and keep it clean.

Enough comparing image filename, but if come with thumnbnails/dates great.

Thanks

Comment: Execute `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE` and save all filenames which are registered in the table into text file. Then process this file using any shell script and remove files which are not listed. PS. I doubt that there exists any pre-made instrument for this task which looks like exotic one.

Comment: Please be more specific what do you mean by "compare". Do you want to compare the binary data? Or just the filename and file size? Also, what is in your database table?

Comment: share your code snippet what you tried

Comment: @Sundar snnipet added...

Answer (score 0):

Top of the file

```
   if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
        unlink($_GET['delete']);
         header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
    
  function getImagesFromDir($path) {
    $images = array();
    if ( $img_dir = @opendir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$path) ) {
        while ( false !== ($img_file = readdir($img_dir)) ) {
            // checks for gif, jpg, png
            if ( preg_match("/(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$/", $img_file) ) {
                $images[] = $img_file;
            }
        }
        closedir($img_dir);
    }
    return $images;
}
```

Custom Form to select mysql TABLE and FIELD name as well as SERVER FOLDERS

```
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
      <div class="form-group">
      <select name="tablename">
  <option value="<?php if (isset($_GET['tablename'])) { echo $_GET['tablename']; } ?>"><?php if (isset($_GET['tablename'])) { echo $_GET['tablename']; } ?></option>          
        <option value="TABLENAME1">TABLENAME1</option>
        <option value="TABLENAME2">TABLENAME2</option>
      </select>
      <select name="fieldname">
  <option value="<?php if (isset($_GET['fieldname'])) { echo $_GET['fieldname']; } ?>"><?php if (isset($_GET['fieldname'])) { echo $_GET['fieldname']; } ?></option>          
        <option value="FIELDNAME1">FIELDNAME1</option>
        <option value="FIELDNAME2">FIELDNAME2</option>
      </select>
       <select name="folder">
  <option value="<?php if (isset($_GET['folder'])) { echo $_GET['folder']; } ?>"><?php if (isset($_GET['folder'])) { echo $_GET['folder']; } ?></option>          
        <option value="RELATIVE_PATH_1"</option>
        <option value="RELATIVE_PATH_2"</option>
      </select>                 
      <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
      </div>
      </form>
```

Now let's retrieve the images from the FOLDER that DON'T EXISTS ON THE DATABASE TABLE AS PER REQUEST ON THE FORM:

```
<?php if ((isset($_GET['tablename'])) && (isset($_GET['fieldname'])) && (isset($_GET['folder'])) ) {

    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password, array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ));
    if (isset($_GET['tablename'])) { 
                $table = $_GET['tablename'];
            } 
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table");
    $query->execute();
     $dbimages = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     if ((!$query->rowCount() == 0)) {  
     $arraydbimg = array();
     foreach ($dbimages as $row => $result) {   
     $arraydbimg[] = $result['img'];
                } 
        } 

    if (isset($_GET['folder'])) { 
                $path = $_GET['folder'];
            } else {
                $path = '/your-default/images-folder/'; 
            }
                        $imgList = getImagesFromDir($path);                         
                        $i=0;
                        foreach ($imgList as &$img) {   
                        if (!in_array($img, $arraydbimg)) { ?>
                                <br clear="all">                            
                                <a href="admin.php?delete=<?php echo urlencode($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. $path . $img); ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo $path . $img ?>" width="150px" height="auto" style="border-radius:0; margin:10px; border:1px #333 solid" /> 
                                </a><?php echo $img; ?>
                        <?  }   } } ?>
```

CLICK ON THE IMAGE JUST IF YOU WANT TO ERASE!

Comment: I know it's dirty but makes the job at the moment.